# Swift presentViewController from superclass doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I have a superclass that has a function that should present a view controller on the subclass. I have two subclass from the superclass and it should present over whichever is currently visible. At the moment it only presents from one of them and only while it is visible.

Skeleton code:

```
class Superclass : UIViewController {
    func somethingHappened() {
        if let navigation = self.navigationController {
            navigation.presentViewController(controllerToPresent, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
                // Stuff
            })
        } else {
            self.presentViewController(controllerToPresent, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
                // Stuff
            })
        }
    }
}
```

One of my view controllers `SubclassA` is the root view controller of a navigation controller and that goes through the `else` of the function.  The other `SubclassB` is pushed over `SubclassA` and that goes through the first part. `SubclassB` is the only view controller that successfully presents the view controller.

`controllerToPresent` is also not nil.

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController> on <SubclassB> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Comment: OK, so what is your question?

Comment: Why won't the view controller on `SubclassA` and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What the warning is trying to tell you is that you are calling the method `presentViewController:animated:completion:` on an instance of `SubclassA` but the view of that instance of `SubclassA` is not in the view hierarchy.

What might fix your problem is to add the view to the view hierarchy before presenting the view controller, for example, by calling

```
view.addSubview(<InstanceOfSubclass>.view)
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me... The view is visible and has been visible for at least 10 seconds.. why would it try and call it on the view that is no longer there rather than the one that is there?

Comment: Maybe you are calling it on a different instance whose view is not visible. I would need more detail to try and help you... You could check that it is in the view hierarchy by checking if its superview is not nil